# a C-program using some posix commands

Tags: c

error: request for member `st_mode' in something not a structure or union

error: syntax error before ')' token

error: incompatible type for argument 1 of `read'

```
/* Here is the code */

int main( int argc, char **argv)

{

    int src, dst;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    int n;

    if (argc!=3)
    {
      printf("\n usage: copy src dst\n");
      return -1;
    }

  struct stat src;

  if(stat(argv[1],&src) < 0)

  return 1;

  printf("File Permissions for source file: \t");

  printf("%d", S_ISDIR(src.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");

  printf(src.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");

  printf(src.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");

  printf(src.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");


  int creat(char *dst,int perms);


  printf("File Permissions for destination file: \t");

  printf(S_ISDIR(src.st_mode)) ? "d" : "-");

  printf(dst.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");

  printf(dst.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");

  printf(dst.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");


  src=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR |S_IXUSR | );

  dst=open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR |S_IXUSR);

  while ((n=read(src, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0)

  {

    if (write(dst, buf, n) != n)

    printf("write error!");

  }

   if (n<0){

   printf("read error !");

  }

   close(src);

   close(dst);

   exit(0);

}
```

Comment: What's the question?  What does the title mean?  Why is there so much vertical space in the code, making it difficult to read?  Please make it easier for us to help you!

Answer (score 5):

Your approach to writing code is wrong, there's a huge list of syntax errors in what you have posted (unless that's a copy/paste effect). You wrote a bunch of lines and then try to compile them. That won't work. In your learning phase you should try to compile your code every 2 lines and try to run it every 4 lines (really).

To summarize:

- most of your ternary operators `... ? ... : ...` have mismatching parentheses
- you call the "." operator on an `int` (`dst`). "dot" is only available on struct types.
- your identation is all out of place, try to improve it
- There's a function declaration in the body of another function, it should be before the function using it.

Comment: +1. Re: "you call the "." operator on an `int` (`dst`)": and also on `src`, which is declared both as an `int` and as a `struct stat`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to declare `dst` as a `struct stat`.  It's currently declared as an `int`.
2. You have two `))` where you only need one.
3. Your first argument to `read` should not be a `struct stat`.

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of data types.  Go study up on them.  Also, you have a lot of redeclared symbols that are making things confusing.  I believe if you compile with `-Wall` it will warn you about doing stuff like that, if it doesn't already.